# Python Pickle Module: Exception Handling with loading lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, pickle

I'm a programming student and doing a simple project that creates a list based on user criteria

I'm having trouble with this part using the Pickle Function.  How can I make it so if the user inputs a list that is not in the directory, it will print an error message and not crash the code.

My teacher said this is called exception handling.

I just want it to not crash and instead ask the user to input another name.

Here's my code.

```
    import pickle

GetList = input("Enter the List to load: ")

with open(GetList, 'rb') as f:
    mylist = pickle.load(f)

print(mylist)
print(J)
```

Comment: The import line is indented wrong just delete the tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply nest a try catch in a while loop to keep asking the user for a different filename if it doesn't work.

```
import pickle

while True:
    try:
        GetList = input("Enter the List to load: ")
        with open(GetList, 'rb') as f:
            mylist = pickle.load(f)
    except (IOError, OSError, pickle.PickleError, pickle.UnpicklingError):
        print("Not a valid file please try again")
    else:
        break
```

Hope this helps.